# Browser flickering on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, display, browser

Got a new Desktop. Motherboard: Gigabyte A320M-H, Processor: Ryzen 3 3200G, and Display: Benq GW2480 24 inch. Things are smooth, though quite frequently, the contents on the browser (both chrome and firefox) gets distorted as shown in the following images.

[image]

[image]

What is happening here?

Comment: not a suitable question in this community. maybe it's an issue with your graphic driver. go ask ubuntu community.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a Zotac Geforce GT 710 graphic card solved the problem.